# Porque no consigo obtener las cookies

Tags: python, cookies

```
from http.cookiejar import *
from urllib.request import *
test = CookieJar()
abridor = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(test))
abridor.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0')]
abridor.open("http://afr232elldh.elbruto.es")
print(test)
```

El objetivo es obtener las Cookies, de la pagina http://afr232elldh.elbruto.es

A que se debe, la no obtención de los datos ?

> Respuesta: Por seguridad.

Esta respuesta no me vale

Comment: ¿qué tipo de respuesta **sí** vale?

Comment: Deberias tomarte algo de tiempo y explicar que es lo que intentas hacer si quieres respuestas que te sean de utilidad.  Si pretendes mediante scraping hacer un login en la página por supuesto que puedes si pretendes romper la seguridad del sitio para acceder a una cuenta ajena entonces es otro tema. Lo de no capturar cookie alguna, para empezar ¿usa cookies la página en ese momento? porque Firefox dice que 0.....

Answer (score 2):

Por definición una página web no tiene estado... cada vez que se recarga se pierde toda su información y se resetean todos sus valores. Cuando se necesita que una página tenga estado es necesario almacenar cierta información en el navegador web... esta información se presenta en forma de cookies, que no son más que pequeños ficheros que almacenan variables indicadas por la página.

El navegador únicamente te permite leer las cookies que pertenecen al dominio de la página ¿por qué? por seguridad y por privacidad.

- Por seguridad: Si todas las cookies fuesen accesibles por cualquier página una web maliciosa lo tendría demasiado facil para recuperar los datos de sesión de tu banco, lo que podría incluso permitir realizar transferencias de dinero.
- Por privacidad: Limitar el acceso a las cookies impide que una página pueda husmear en las mismas buscando historiales de navegación. Esto último con Google y su publicidad omnipresente pierde algo de sentido, pero aun así esta política limita en parte tu exposición.

Lo siento si no te gustan este tipo de respuestas pero es lo que hay. Siempre puedes intentar romper los sistemas de protección del navegador para acceder a cookies ajenas, pero luego no te sorprendas si el navegador de turno saca un parche para evitar esa intromisión.